# How to change Horizontal bar chart to vertical bar chart in D3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I have a Horizontal bar chart in D3, but I'd like to have a vertical bar chart instead of a horizontal. Here's what it looks like now. I tried fiddling with the X and Y axes and can't seem to get it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Layered Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var dataArray = [10, 20, 40, 60];

var canvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500);

var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'base')
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return d * 10;
        })
        .attr("height", 30)
        .attr("y", function(d, i){
            return i * 35;
        })
        .attr("fill", "blue");
        //.attr("fill-width", "green");
        
/*
canvas.append("text")
    .text(function(d){
        return d;
    }).attr;
*/

var dataArray1 = [5, 10, 20, 30];

var bars1 = canvas.selectAll("rect.addon")
    .data(dataArray1)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'addon')
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return d * 7;
        })
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("y", function(d, i){
            return (i*35) + 5;
        })
        .attr("fill", "red");
        //.attr("fill-width", "black");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to: 1. change the scales, including domains and ranges; 2. change the axes generators and the axes' groups; 3. change the logic of `x`, `y`, `height` and `width` attributes for the rectangles. A lot of work for you to have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gerardo.Could you please Find the code above and mention in Code where I have to change.Thanks.This will help me a lot.

Comment: I already told you what must be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of conversion you need to change more than x and y.

Using your example code, the chart's shape will be dictated by the four properties of each rectangle: `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`. Afterall, (generally) a vertical bar chart does not have the same height for each bar, while a horizontal bar chart does.

Secondly, most vertical bar charts have the rects anchored on the bottom while most horizontal bar charts have the rects anchored to the left. In svg coordinate space the top of the svg is y = 0, while the left of the svg is x = 0. Consequently, simply swapping `x` and `y` , `width` and `height` in your example will result in a bar chart that has bars reaching down from the top of the chart.

To solve this, you need to modify the `y` attribute of each rectangle. As the `y` attribute sets the top of the rectangle, you need to figure out the top of each rectangle. For your code:

```
.attr("y", function(d,i) { return heightOfSVG - heightOfRectangle; }) // bottom of rectangle - rectangle height = rectangle top
```

This line is new as you didn't set the x attribute in your original code, instead using the default zero. This won't do in the vertical graph, as the top of the rectangle can't be at y = 0 (in most cases).

The use of scales of course will complicate this, as will labelled axes, or multiple-series bar charts etc. I've used your code, as it was provided. I've stripped your example to one chart as opposed to two to show what those changes might look like applied to a minimal example of a scale-less graph.

```js
var canvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500);

var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data([10, 20, 40, 60])
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("height", function(d){  
            return d * 10;
        })
        .attr("width", 30)
        .attr("x", function(d, i){
            return i * 35;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return 500 - d * 10; })
        .attr("fill", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. this is actually I want